# How to show $\lim_{x\to 1}2^{1/(x-1)} $ does not exist?

Tags: limits

> How to show $$\lim \limits_{x\to 1}2^{\frac{1}{x-1}} $$ doesn't exist?

I understand that we have to show the left-hand limit is not equal to the right-hand limit. But how to do that?

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Answer (score 3):

Let $f(x)=2^{\frac{1}{x-1}}$ and $x_n:=1+1/n$. Then

$f(x_n)=2^n \to \infty$ for $n \to \infty$.

If $y_n=1-1/n$, then $f(y_n)=1/2^n \to 0$ for $n \to \infty$.

Answer (score 2):

Since$$\lim_{x\to1^+}2^{\frac1{x-1}}=2^{+\infty}=+\infty\text{ and }\lim_{x\to1^-}2^{\frac1{x-1}}=2^{-\infty}=0,$$the limit does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

As $x \to 1^-$ (from the left), you have that $x-1$ is always negative but never cero, hence $\frac{1}{x-1} \to - \infty$.

On the other side, as $x \to 1^+$ (from the right), you have that $x-1$ is always positive but never cero, hence $\frac{1}{x-1} \to \infty$.

Therefore, the limit does not exist since the limits from the left and the right does not coincide.

Answer (score 0):

$y:=x-1.$

Consider:

1) $\lim _{y \rightarrow 0^+} 2^{1/y}.$

Let $(y_n) := 1/n$, $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} 2^n$  $\rightarrow \infty.$

2) What happens if you choose

$(y_n): = - (1/n)$ ?